# May adult Ashkenazim kiss their children in shul?

Tags: halacha, synagogue, kissing

in shulchan aruch orach chayim 98:1 the Rama writes
 וְאָסוּר לְאָדָם לְנַשֵּׁק בָּנָיו הַקְּטַנִּים בְּבֵית הַכְּנֶסֶת, כְּדֵי לִקְבֹּעַ בְּלִבּוֹ שֶׁאֵין אַהֲבָה כְּאַהֲבַת הַמָּקוֹם בָּרוּךְ הוּא (בִּנְיָמִין זְאֵב סי' קס''ג וַאֲגֻדָּה פ' כֵּיצַד מְבָרְכִין).
i am wondering if any contemporary authorities deal with this issue. in my experience this psak is not practiced in many communities.

Answer (score 5):

Rav Ari Enkin [discusses](http://hirhurim.blogspot.com/2010/06/kissing-children-in-shul.html) both sides of the questions, but to see sources who allow it:

> Nevertheless, it is permitted to kiss one's child in the synagogue if
>   necessary in order to calm him down after getting hurt, or the
>   like.[Rivevot Ephraim 2:61, Veharev Na;Shemot, Aleinu Leshabeiach p.579] One is also permitted to kiss one's child in order to make
>   the child feel important, encouraged, or as praise for something
>   positive the child has done, such as asking or answering a sharp Torah
>   question.[Veharev Na;Shemot] This is similar to the custom of the Talmudic sages who
>   would kiss one who has delivered an impressive Torah discourse. This
>   was practiced both in the synagogue and even in the Beit
>   Hamikdash.[Avot D'rabbi Natan 6, Nedarim 96, Kalla 1:21. See Piskei Teshuvot 98 note 70]
>
> Finally, there is a view among some halachic authorities that the
>   prohibition against kissing one's children in the synagogue applies
>   only while services are being conducted, but is permissible at all
>   other times.[Piskei Teshuvot 98:7] This innovative ruling is based on the observation
>   that the halacha which forbids kissing in the synagogue is codified in
>   the Shulchan Aruch under "The Laws of Prayer" and not under "The Laws
>   of the Synagogue".